# Getting data from 2 tables by JOIN, when @Foreign Keys exist to the same Table/Object

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, query

I have 2 Tables:

```
User

id | name | email  | staff
1    name1  email1   true
2    name2  email2   no
3    name3  email3   true
4    name4  email4   no


Note

id | text | sender_id | receiver_id
1    text1    1            2 
2    text2    1            3
3    text3    1            2   
4    text4    3            2
```

Note has 2 Foreign Keys to the User, sender_id and receiver_id.

I want to get in a Select(one if possible) the data (name, email, staff) of both the sender and the receiver/.

I tried :

```
  SELECT N.text, U.name, U.email from Note as N 
    LEFT JOIN User as U on Note.sender_id = U.id where U.staff is True ...
```

but this way I'm getting the sender only.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `User` table twice:

```
SELECT N.text, S.name, S.email, R.name, R.email
FROM   Note as N 
   LEFT JOIN User as S on N.sender_id = S.id where S.staff is True       
   LEFT JOIN User as R on N.sender_id = R.id where R.staff is True
```